# Show that a map is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,d)$ be a metric space where $\Omega=\{0,1,..,9\}$ is finite set and $d$ is discrete metric.and $(\Omega^{\infty},\mathcal {F})$ be measurable space where $\mathcal {F}$ is product $\sigma-$ algebra.Consider the map $f: \Omega^{\infty} \setminus $ eventually zero sequences $\to (0,1]$ defined as $f(w) = \sum_n \frac {w_n}{10^n}$.Show that

> $f$ is a bi-measurable bijection.

I have proved that $f$ is a bijection but i am unable to prove that $f$ is measurable.Please help

Comment: Show each term $w_n/10^n$ is measurable.  The sum of a convergent series of measurable functions is measurable.

Comment: @GEdgar So you're saying that fiber of each point is measurable because fiber has just one point?